# Grub rescue after corrupted hard-drive ("read-only filesystem")

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, ext4, ntfs, xubuntu

I run xubuntu 12.04 alongside a NTFS storage partition and a windows 8 partition.

I moved my MySQL data directory off the xubuntu (ext4) partition, onto the NTFS partition, and did an import of a database. I left it running overnight, and in the morning, I had a filesystem crash (everything was read-only). Now when I try to boot the computer, I am taken to grub rescue.

`grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,gpt8) (hd0,gpt7) (hd0,gpt6) (hd0,gpt5) (hd0,gpt4) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1) (hd1)`

I tried `ls` on all of these partitions, and all but two said `error: unknown filesystem`. The other two said:

`` grub rescue> ls (hd0,gpt8)
error: invalid file name `'. ``

`grub rescue> ls (hd0,gpt8)/
./ ../ lost+found/ OS/ Downloads/ .Trash-1000/ ...` <- promising, but only shows a subset of folders

`` grub rescue> ls (hd1)
error: failure reading sector 0x0 from `hd1.' ``

Most of the other boot rescue posts on askubuntu are about failures during installation, so I'm not sure their advice to run boot-repair applies here.

Next steps?

Comment: I suggest booting from a CD / DVD / USB stick. You can run `fsck` from there if the partitions cannot be mounted. If you have a spare drive you may consider making a sector copy (`dd`) before running `fsck`.

Comment: I did, and took log of the errors, as well as a TestDisk, but I didn't get it onto the Live USB successfully. Oops. I will redo that and update tonight/tomorrow.